# playing audio from audio track in android

Tags: android, audio

I want to play music from an online mp3 link.

I am reading the music data into a stream and trying to play it using audio track.

But it's giving only noise. I can't hear any music

This is my code.

```
int  intSize = android.media.AudioTrack.getMinBufferSize(8000,
                    AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO,
                    AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);

AudioTrack oTrack = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 8000,
                    AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO,
                    AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, intSize,
                    AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);

oTrack.play();
oTrack.write(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
```

Here buffer is the audio data I am reading into.

Same buffers I can play in MediaPlayer, but I could not play in audiotrack.

What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: I would put 4 spaces at the begging of each line containing code.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently AudioTrack only plays PCM audio, so either you will have to find a way to decode the MP3 into PCM yourself, or use MediaPlayer instead which can do the decoding for you (according to http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/index.html ).